# Why are SelectedItems missing in IntelliSense on ListBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, listbox

Am I missing something here?
I can't find the `SelectedItems` property on `ListBox` control. I'm trying to loop through the selected items in it. And yes, property `SelectionMode` is set to multiple, not that it matters.

Why can't I 'see' the property?

Comment: soooo whats the problem?

Comment: the problem was that I couldnt find the selected items. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: 2 people are defnently missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Important:** I had mistaken this for a Windows Forms question.
>   The following is **not** true for `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox`. It's about the Windows Forms `ListBox`

It [does exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) but is marked with

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
```

so IntelliSense won't show it to you, but you can use it anyways.

---

A proper solution that also works for the ASP.NET `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox` would be:

```
var selectedItems = from item in myListBox.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                    where item.Selected;
```

Comment: You can't use it anyways, I get a compile error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItems'

Comment: Also your link is a link to a Listbox in System.Windows.Forms, not ASP.NET

Comment: Oh.. I really thought this was a windows forms question. I overlooked the asp.net tag. Strange that my answer has been accepted then.

Comment: Ok I removed downvote, since you correctly updated your answer. Maybe it 'kinda' was an answer, since the OP was asking for SelectedItems property, but it doesn't exist in asp.net, only in win forms.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I didnt actually test it, just took your word for it. I came up with another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Noah1989 for pointing out that `SelectedItems` property is **not** available in WebForms.
To overcome this, just loop through all the items in the listbox, and ask if they're selected:

```
ListItemCollection collection = new ListItemCollection();
            foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                    collection.Add(item);
            }
```

or as Noah said - just use LINQ: `from item in items where item.IsSelected`

Comment: since you're using .net 4.0, you could still use the LINQ-based solution instead of that loop (which looks like a stranger from the old .net times)

Comment: @noah1989 oh didnt see your updated answer there with the linq. Ill mark your question as the accepted answer.

Comment: So you blame Noah1989 aka @StefanPaulNoack for the property not being available in WebForms? ;)

Comment: @Nurp hahaha looks like it. Bad english.

Comment: I'm really sorry for not providing SelectedItems in WebForms ;-)

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack You guys really making me edit a post from 2012. Ffs :-D